# Conditional code based on a device's language in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I'm trying to create if statements based on the device's language.

For instance:
if device's language is English ()
else if device's language is Spanish ()
else if device's language is Arabic ()
...etc.

but cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193284/check-language-in-ios-app .... You can find iOS language codes here: http://www.ibabbleon.com/iOS-Language-Codes-ISO-639.html ... @alexburtnik is correct, you use NSLocale.preferredLanguages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two parts. The first is to get the current language from the current locale.

Swift 3:

```
let languageCode = Locale.current.languageCode
```

The second part is to check which language it is:

```
if let languageCode = Locale.current.languageCode {
    switch languageCode {
        case "en":
            // handle English
        case "es":
            // handle Spanish
        case "ar":
            // handle Arabic
        default:
            // handle others
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working @rmaddy, can you please check my question here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67516514/1559675

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NSLocale](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nslocale)'s `preferredLanguages` method:

```
let language = NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]

if language.hasPrefix("en") {
    //english
}
else if language.hasPrefix("ar") {
    //arabic
}
```

Comment: That's not the correct way to get the device's language.

Comment: @rmaddy You're welcome to provide a better solution ;)

Comment: @RayX1993: In fact rmaddy provided a cleaner solution, you should use it and upvote. However, both work as expected.