# How to get iOS device system language?

Tags: ios, swift

How to get system device language, using Swift iOS? Not app language, that I am having no issue.

I want to get device language from *Setting -> General -> Language* that user set language to.

I tried below code:

```swift
let appLang = Locale.preferredLanguages
print("appLang ======== \(appLang)")

let bungleLang = Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations
print("bungleLang ======== \(bungleLang)")

let code = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent.languageCode
print("code ======== \(code ?? "")")

if let code = Locale.current.languageCode {
    print("Locale.current.languageCode ======== \(code)")
}

print("currentLanguage ======== \(Localize.currentLanguage())")

let local = getPreferredLocale()
print("local ======== \(local)")
print("languageCode = \(local.languageCode ?? "")")
print("regionCode = \(local.regionCode ?? "")")
```

Output:

```
appLang ======== ["en"]
bungleLang ======== ["en"]
code ======== en
Locale.current.languageCode ======== en
currentLanguage ======== en
local ======== en (fixed)
languageCode = en
regionCode =
```

So I am not getting device language, whatever the user set in his device settings.

Question:

Is it possible or not? I tried everything.

All code getting only `en` or *English*, but if the user set the language to Italian then? How we can get *Italian* or `it`?

**Note:** Again I am saying I am not talking about app language, I am talking about device language.

Not working in simulator and real device both

- Checked in Simulator iPhone 11, iOS 14.4
- Checked in Real Device iPhone 7, iOS 13.3
- Xcode Version 12.4

**Also tried:**
UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "AppleLanguages")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current language code with Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591167/how-to-get-current-language-code-with-swift)

Comment: @Raptor no I tried everything from that link as well. you can check my code above and output, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "AppleLanguages")
```

The output will be like - `["en-US"]`.

It'll return an array with language codes, first index is the current language set in iPhone's setting (it'll be a single item array if the preferred language order in settings is empty.)

Comment: No, same issue only getting ["en"], I checked in both simulator and real device. In my preferred language in setting there are two languages in list Italian and English.

Comment: It worked for me. check for manage scheme under app target for app language and app region to system.

Comment: It worked, but just for others - App Target -> Edit Scheme -> App Language change to system language. And all variable will work not only "AppLanguages" but also you will get proper for all other variables like "preferredLanguages" "languageCode" etc... Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried `Locale.current.identifier`?
[image: current identifier]