# How to check if my user is from a specific country Ios, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, localization, location

In my app I want to take the phone number of my user but I have a restriction of how the phone number starts, this is for Greece but I don't want my users outside of Greece to have this restriction.

So is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use a geolocation database to look up the user's location. It is not 100% reliable, but probably good enough for most applications/situations.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @johnelemans but if the user doesn't accept the dialog for user location then I couldn't take his location

Comment: You can with the ip address. it doesn't use location services.

Comment: Oh do you know any resource I can check it out

Comment: here's one;  http://lite.ip2location.com/

Comment: But what happens when the user is traveling? A user with a Greek phone number still has a Greek phone number if they're in Miami.

Comment: You are right @BSMP but its no so important to don't have a restriction to some users (outside of greece there will not be a restriction) so a greek phone number will be also can be entered

Comment: @BSMP of course if you re thinking another way I ll be glad if you share it

Comment: See if this helps [Get Language Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193284/check-language-in-ios-app)

Comment: @MwcsMac thanks for your comment Is this returns the language or the region that the user have registered to his device

Comment: One option is to ask the user to enter their phone number and send a verification code to check that they actually owns that number. [Apple does not allow you to get the user phone's number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-ios)

Comment: After i search a little i found something (how to get the region that the user selected when he activated his phone(not the system lang)) i will post it tommorrow. @CodeDifferent do i have to pay for the verification?

Comment: You can use the user's region code but it can be easily changed. Sending text messages will incur a small cost. Check around for one that suits you best. Examples: [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com), [Authy](https://www.authy.com/developers/), [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/details/mfa/), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After considering what we said in comments I found a way to do it.
I use the country that the user registered when he first open his phone like that:

```
var localeArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    localeArray = NSLocale.currentLocale().localeIdentifier.componentsSeparatedByString("_")


        }


func takeResult() {

   if localeArray[1] == "GR" {

       //do what you want
   }else {

      //handle if the user isn't in the country you want
   }
}
```

The first result of `localArray` (`localArray[0]`) is the system language that the user has.

EDIT FOR SWIFT 3

This is how you get the same result with swift 3 found it [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-detect-which-country-a-user-is-in)

```
let locale = Locale.current
print(locale.regionCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSLocale` is just a setting about currently used regional settings, it doesn't mean the actual country you're in.

Use `CLLocationManager` to get current `location` & `CLGeocoder` to perform reverse-geocoding. You can get country name from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but first If the user don't accept the location privacy I will not have his country, and then If the user has set the country Greece then I know he will have a greek number so If someone is for vacation but has greek number I want the restriction